# Java connect timed out in intellij and gradle build, but not curl

Tags: java, http, debugging, networking, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have an endpoint that I'm testing in my java project built with gradle. When I run tests using gradle build, I always get "connect timed out" errors. These timeouts also happen when I run the junit test within Intellij.

```
// domain and IPs redacted

Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to {domain}:80 [{domain}/{ip}, {domain}/{ip2}] failed: connect timed out
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:551)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.internalExecute(MainClientExec.java:382)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:241)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:97)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:59)
    at com.apple.shuttlebus2.client.http.SBHttp._execute(SBHttp.java:1006)
    at com.apple.shuttlebus2.client.http.SBHttpCommand.run(SBHttpCommand.java:323)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
```

However when I straight up curl the endpoint I always get a success. I know the client I'm using is correct because it works for other environment endpoints without any code changes.

Struggling to find out why this endpoint would work through curl, but not a gradle build on the same machine and network.

Comment: Edit your question and include the code.  We don’t need to see the hostname, but we do need to see how you’re building your request and your client.

Answer (score 0):

If the project with the tests also runs the endpoint, be sure to use the annotations to raise the context when running the tests.

If you are using Spring maybe [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/#:%7E:text=.SpringBootTest%3B-,%40SpringBootTest,-public%20class%20TestingWebApplicationTests) would help.